# is there any legitimate reason to use ViewData in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

with model binding where you can build up an object to ship and bind to the view, is there any reason to ever use ViewData ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't forsee an instance where I would use it unless I had static information coming in from a database for a page/master that then got displayed in say a `<p>` or some such.

If the page was a read only page that say returned a list of items and I also wanted to display text from a DB then I might use ViewData.

But that's kind of an exception.  If I was returning a list of items from a DB along with some other stuff then I would create a Form View Model and simply include any other data in with it.

So rarely I guess is my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

ViewData seems to exist as a simple, convenient approach to something that you really should do a syntactically cleaner way. The MVC equivalent of an ArrayList I suppose- works just fine but you'd be hard pressed to come up with a truly legitimate excuse for using it in good code.

One exception I can think of for using it would be including something dynamic in ALL of your pages that gets appended in an ActionFilter or base Controller class- for example "WebsiteTitle". Rather than attempting to tamper with the data being returned by a Controller action it might make more sense to include something like that in the ViewData collection- perhaps prefixed with some unique identifier to make it obvious it was being included outside the controller action. `ViewData["Base_WebSiteName"]`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to MVC but what little I have done, I have written custom objects for all my views.

The only reason I could think of is to save time.  You need to whip something up fast and maybe there are multiple objects of data on a page and something extra and you don't want to take the time to write an object putting it all together.  Is this a good reason?  In my opinion no.

Comment: Yeah a less than adequate reason really.  If it's worth writting, even as a demo, it's worth doing right.  Demos almost always end up as product anyway. :)